# Find the greatest integer less than or equal to $\sum\limits_{n=1}^{9999} \frac {1} {n^{\frac 1 4}}.$

Tags: number-theory, ceiling-and-floor-functions

> Find the greatest integer less than or equal to $$\sum\limits_{n=1}^{9999} \frac {1} {n^{\frac 1 4}}.$$

I have tried but failed. Is there any elementary way to find this out? Any help will be highly appreciated.

Thank you very much for your valuable time.

Comment: This might help https://artofproblemsolving.com/community/c6h1970811p13660392

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since $x^{-1/4}$ is decreasing, then

$$\underbrace{\int_1^{10,000}\frac1{x^{1/4}}\,dx}_{1,332} \le \sum_{n=1}^{9999}\frac1{n^{1/4}}\le 1+\underbrace{\int_1^{9999}\frac1{x^{1/4}}\,dx}_{=\frac43 ((9999)^{3/4}-1)}$$

Can you convince yourself that the right-hand side is less than 1,333?

Comment: Definitely. Because $\frac 4 3 \left ( (9999)^{\frac 3 4} - 1 \right ) < 1332$ and $\frac {1} {{9999}^{\frac 1 4}} < 1$ and hence clearly the right hand side is less than $1333.$

Comment: In the right hand inequality I think you have made a mistake. If $f : (0, \infty) \longrightarrow \Bbb R$ is a continuous monotonic decreasing function then for any natural number $k \in \Bbb N$ what I observe is that if I take a partition of $[1,n]$ by means of unit intervals $[r,r+1],$ $1 \leq r \leq n-1$ then the lower Riemann sum of $f$ corresponding to that partition of $[1,n]$ becomes $\sum\limits_{n=2}^{k} f(n),$ since $f$ is monotonic decreasing. So $\sum\limits_{n=2}^{k} f(n) \leq \int_{1}^{n} f(x)\ dx.$

Comment: Hence $$\sum\limits_{n=1}^{k} f(n) = f(1) + \sum\limits_{n=2}^{k} f(n) \leq f(1) + \int_{1}^{n} f(x)\ dx.$$ Please correct me if I'm wrong.

Comment: So in this case we must have $$\sum\limits_{n=1}^{9999} \frac {1} {n^{\frac 1 4}} \leq 1 + \int_{1}^{9999} \frac {1} {x^{\frac 1 4}}\ dx.$$ Since $$\int_{1}^{9999} \frac {1} {x^{\frac 1 4}}\ dx = \frac {4} {3} \left ( (9999)^{\frac 3 4} - 1 \right ) < 1332$$ we have $\sum\limits_{n=1}^{9999} \frac {1} {n^{\frac 1 4}} < 1333,$ as required.

Comment: Please give it a look @Mark Viola.

Comment: Sorry some mistake. The general integral I define should be $\int_{1}^{k} f(x)\ dx$ instead of $\int_{1}^{n} f(x)\ dx.$

Comment: @mathmaniac Yes indeed.  I've edited accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

Consider the function $f(x)=\frac{4}{3} x^{\frac{3}{4}}, f:[k, k+1] \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$, and we apply the MVT theoreme, so we can write: $\frac{1}{\sqrt[4]{k+1}}<f(k+1)-f(k)<\frac{1}{\sqrt[4]{k}}$. Denote $S_{n}=\sum_{k=1}^{n} \frac{1}{\sqrt[4]{k}}$, so after the summarization
we get: $S_{n}-1<f(n)-\int(1)<S_{n}-\frac{1}{\sqrt[4]{n}} \Leftrightarrow \frac{4}{3} n^{\frac{3}{4}}+\frac{1}{\sqrt[4]{n}}-\frac{4}{3}<S_{n}<\frac{4}{3} n^{\frac{3}{2}}-\frac{1}{3}$, and
replace $n=9999$.